# Strange operators "|="

Tags: c++, c, operators

i'm relatively new to coding, anyway i came across this if statement while copying a tutorial for an iphone pixel technique, anyway i'm not really sure what it's doing so if anybody could explain it for me it would be awesome thanks.

```
for(int j = 0; j < (width * height); j++ ) 
{
    if ( pixels[j] & 0xff000000 )  
    {
        collisionMap[j] |= 1;
    }
}
```

The parts that confuse me are the '|=' and the single '&' sign. What's going on here? Thanks

Comment: Please tag this as C++. This will not compile in C, because of the variable declaration inside the for loop.

Comment: @Lundin: It will compile with any C99 compliant compiler and it will compile with even pre-C99 gcc without `-ansi` or `-std=c89` option.

Comment: @Jan Ah dang it, you are right, I had forgotten that C99 allows it. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: That's understandable - it's been around for only 12 years, so it is a fairly new thing in the C evolution timescale `:)`

Answer (score 6):

& is a [bitwise AND.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

|= is a [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) and assigns the value to `collisionMap[j]`.

Comment: That is to say that "collisionMap[j] |= 1;" is the same as "collisionMap[j] = collisionMap[j] | 1;"

Answer (score 4):

They are called [bitwise operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

`collisionMap[j] |= 1` is equivalent to `collisionMap[j] = collisionMap[j] | 1`

Which will make sure the LSB of `collisionMap[j]` is set

Answer (score 1):

`|=` performs a bitwise OR of the values on either side (considering precendence), putting the result into the left-side variable.  So, `a |= b` is the same as `a = a | b` (assuming no C++ operator overloading).  More concretely, say:

```
a is 01010000 binary, and
b is 10011001 binary, then after `a |= b`...
a is 11011001.
```

`&` performs a bitwise AND, resulting in a value with only the bits from the values on either side.

Comment: ahhhh ok, thanks guys i understand now, you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The single & does a bitwise and, while the `|=` operator does a bitwise or.

Comment: Strictly: `|` is bitwise-or, `|=` is bitwise-or-assignment